# JNDI connection pool

Tags: java, connection, jndi, connection-pooling

I am currently working on java project which is based on struts and tomcat 7.Now due to memory reasons I am planning to convert the project from using normal JDBC/ODBC connections to JNDI connection pooling.Am kind of stuck here.What are the basic changes that I should make in the code as part of this conversion.Should I change the configuration of tomcat?Is there any jars that needed to be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tomcat 7 has a robust connection pool implementation and provides a really good [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). It will guide you through the configuration changes you need to make in Tomcat and/or in your application. There are also code examples.

Comment: Thanks Bora.It did help me a lot.